# How to do GeoFencing on Windows Phone mango

Tags: c#, windows-phone-7, geofencing

Can somebody help me or share some code about how to achieve GeoFencing on Windows Phone Mango.

I have list of GeoPositions(Latitude and Longitudes) and on every position update I want to verify that this current position is in that list which we in other words call GeoFencing, but i want to do it locally without touching any WebService etc...
So I want to know is it possible ...

Also I want to achive this without blocking the main UI thread.

Please advice.

Comment: Do your positions define a virtual polygon, or are you interested in proximity to them?

Comment: Have you see the following blog post : http://blogs.msdn.com/b/dragoman/archive/2010/10/13/wp7-code-geofencing-with-the-geolocation-api-and-rx.aspx

Comment: Rowland, by Proximity you mean circle? actually I need both virtual polygon and circle but atleast to go a head what ever is easy and achievable please guide

Comment: Paul, I have seen this but because I am new to Windows Phone I am not much used to RX and it looks quiet complicated, but if this is the only way, i will consult that blog again

Comment: What no body knows my problem?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In the Microsoft sample form the Tidy app (part of the samples for Mango) - in Todo.DataAccess project, `GeoCodeDistanceCalc` static class which calculates the distance between a pair of co-ordinates with:

```
return radius * 2 * Math.Asin(Math.Min(1, Math.Sqrt((Math.Pow(Math.Sin((DiffRadian(lat1, lat2)) / 2.0), 2.0) + Math.Cos(ToRadian(lat1)) * Math.Cos(ToRadian(lat2)) * Math.Pow(Math.Sin((DiffRadian(lng1, lng2)) / 2.0), 2.0)))));
```

(where radius is the radius of the Earth in whatever unit you want the result)

For point in polygon approach, there is a [whole Wikipedia article on the subject](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Point_in_polygon), but in the past, I've found the ray-casting algorithm relatively simple to implement.